# matplotlib FuncAnimation clear plot each repeat cycle

Tags: animation, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

The code below works, but I think is overplotting the original points each repeat cycle. I want it to start from the origin, each repeat cycle, with a clear plot. Amongst many approaches to fixing this, I have tried inserting ax.clear() in both the init and update functions; not effective. I have left in the code what I thought would reset the ln, artist to having an empty set; again this is not the solution I am looking for. I would appreciate some guidance on what the correct way to reinitiate each cycle is in this toy example so that, when applied to my more complex problem, I don't incur cumulative penalties. This works fine in terms of refreshing if passing an array...Thanks for any help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, writers
#from basic_units import radians
# # Set up formatting for the movie files
# Writer = writers['ffmpeg']
# writer = Writer(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Llew'), bitrate=1800)

#Polar stuff
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = plt.subplot(111,polar=True)
ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')
ax.set_rticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])  # fewer radial ticks
ax.set_facecolor(plt.cm.gray(.95))
ax.grid(True)
xT=plt.xticks()[0]
xL=['0',r'$\frac{\pi}{4}$',r'$\frac{\pi}{2}$',r'$\frac{3\pi}{4}$',\
    r'$\pi$',r'$\frac{5\pi}{4}$',r'$\frac{3\pi}{2}$',r'$\frac{7\pi}{4}$']
plt.xticks(xT, xL)
r = []
theta = []
# Animation requirements.
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'r:',
                    markersize=1.5,
                    alpha=1,
                    animated=True)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 2)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    r.append(frame)
    theta.append(5*np.pi*frame)
    ln.set_data(theta, r)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0,2,400),
                    init_func=init, interval=10, blit=True,repeat=True)

plt.show()
```

I tried to reset the lists (and with arrays also) using this somewhat crude approach, which wiped the list, but did not re-initiate the cycle.

```
def update(frame,r,theta):
    r.append(frame)
    theta.append(5*np.pi*frame)
    if len(r)>=400:
        r = [0]
        theta=[0]
    ln.set_data(theta, r)
    return ln,
```

In contrast, this does work as intended...

```
for i in range(25):
    r.append(i)
    print('len(r)',len(r), r)
    if len(r) >=10:
        r = []
        print('if r>=10:',r)
    print('Post conditional clause r',len(r),r)
```

This led me to try the following, noting that passing the internal (r,theta) within the update() outside requires declaring it as a global variable. With the following code, the plot now resets each cycle instead of overplotting. My sense is that this is a rather long way around a simple procedure -- any improvements gratefully accepted.

```
#This solution also works
def update(frame):
        r.append(frame)
        theta.append(5*np.pi*frame)
        if len(r)>=400:
            global r
            r = []
            global theta
            theta=[]
        ln.set_data(theta, r)
        return ln,
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand your code and your question, you want to display only one point at each frame of the animation, is that correct?

If so, your problem is simply that you are *appending* each new point to all previous points in the function `update()`. Instead, simply update the data coordinates, like so:

```
def update(frame):
    r = frame
    theta = 2*np.pi*frame
    ln.set_data(theta, r)
    return ln,
```

[image]

**EDIT** Let's see if I get this right this time around.

You could choose to only show the last `N` points like so:

```
N=10
def update(frame):
    r.append(frame)
    theta.append(2*np.pi*frame)
    ln.set_data(theta[-N:], r[-N:])
    return ln,
```

[image]

or you can append `N` points to your array, then reset to an empty array. I think that might be what you were trying to do. Here, you have to be careful. If you simply do `r = []` then you change which object `r` references to, and that breaks the animation. What you need to do is change the *content* of the array with the syntax `r[:] = []`.

```
def update(frame):
    r_ = frame
    theta_ = 2*np.pi*frame
    if len(r)>N:
        r[:] = [r_]
        theta[:] = [theta_]
    else:    
        r.append(r_)
        theta.append(theta_)
    ln.set_data(theta, r)
    return ln,
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, no -- I want to create an incrementing list (or array), then have the list reset at each repeat cycle. I have tried doing this with arrays and using a variety of constructions. When I tried inserting some form of conditional statement on the length of the list, with it then returning to r=[], for example, within the update function, this stops the function working. I also tried playing with the blit being True/False, with no success.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure what you mean, but I've amended my answer with 2 other possibilities

Comment: Thanks, declaring that r[:] = [] produces the required reset the global r & theta. Have a look at my last try at a solution, setting r and theta as globals within the update() also works. I think the issue is _how to pass the function variables back out of the function to the global variables_ as initially set. If the readers try the code above with each variant of update() the issue seems more clear (I hope). Because inserting the r[:]=[] works will accept your answer with thanks for the help :)

Comment: I think what is happening is that `r[:] = []` replaces the *content* of `r`, which remains global (it was declared outside the function). `r = []` replaces the object `r`, and the new object is therefore no longer global. It has to be re-declared as global to be used later.